# What does it mean for a function $f$ to be continuous almost every where with respect to the measure induced by $g$?

Tags: measure-theory, continuity

In this case $g$ is monotone increasing on the finite interval $[a,b]$. Does this mean that $f$ is continuous in the normal sense of continuity (ie. $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$ when $|x-y|<\delta$) except on a set of measure $0$ where the measure here is the measure induced by $g$?

For clarification here is he whole question I am asked to answer.

> Let $g$ be a monotone function on a finite closed interval $[a,b]$. Show that a bounded function $f$ defined on $[a,b]$ is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable with respect to $g$ iff $f$ is continuous almost everywhere with respect to the measure induced by $g$.

Im guessing the measure induced by $g$ is the Borel measure, $\mu_g$, with the property $\mu_g(a,b) = g(b)-g(a)$ since $g$ is monotone.

Comment: _"the measure induced by $g$"_: you mean $g(x)dx$ or $dg(x)$?

Comment: Riemann-Stieltjes measure induced by $g$?

Comment: @Federico what is the Riemann-Stiltjies measure induced by $g$?

Comment: What is the measure induced by $g$?

Comment: In any case, the answer would be **yes**; regardless of what measure you are considering

Comment: I was referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral

Comment: More likely the push-forward of Lebesgue measure on $[a,b]$ by $g$.  That is, the assertion is that the  set of $x$ such that $f$ is discontinuous at $g(x)$ has L measure 0.

Comment: @Federico I edited the question to give the full question I need to answer

Comment: Yes, so why do you ask me "what is the Riemann-Stiltjies measure induced by $g$"? It's already in your exercise. But as I said, it's completely irrelevant to your question

Comment: @Federico I dont understand what youre asking? Im not asking what the measure induced by $g$ is, I am asking what it means to be almost everywhere continuous with respect to that measure.

Comment: Oh sorry, I realize only now that it wasn't you that asked me "what is the Riemann-Stiltjies measure induced by $g$?". I was mathworker21.